# write stored procedure to delete records

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, delete

There are two tables job run and account interface, as per requirement to write code  to prune associated JobRun records 
(JobRun.AccountId = AccountInterface.AccountID AND JobRun.InterfaceID = AccountInterface.ID) taking this value into account.
since each AccountInterface can have a different AutoPruneJobDays value,  have to consider each independently.  I wrote code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AutoPruneJobRun] 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @PruneDate DATE
DECLARE @AutoPruneJobDays INT

SET @AutoPruneJobDays
   =(
     SELECT MAX(AutoPruneJobDays) AS [AutoPruneJobDays] 
       FROM [dbo].[JobRun] AS JR 
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[AccountInterface] AS AI
         ON JR.[AccountID]=AI.[AccountID]
             AND JR.[InterfaceID]=AI.[ID]

       )

SET @PruneDate=CASE WHEN @AutoPruneJobDays IS NULL OR @AutoPruneJobDays=0 THEN GETDATE()-1
                    ELSE DATEADD(dd,-@AutoPruneJobDays,GETDATE()) END

DELETE FROM [dbo].[JobRun] WHERE [Started]<@PruneDate
end
```

where started is datetime column.but this code is not deleted data as per requirement .for example accountinterface has two accounted 13,13 and autopronejobdays is 30 for both but id is 1,2 resp.
so how to modify code.will it works if

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AutoPruneJobRun] 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @PruneDate DATE = GETUTCDATE()

DELETE jr
FROM [dbo].[JobRun] jr
INNER JOIN [dbo].[AccountInterface] ai 
        ON ai.AccountID = jr.AccountID 
       AND ai.ID        = jr.InterfaceID
WHERE  jr.Started < DATEADD(DAY, -1 * ai.AutoPruneJobDays, @PruneDate)
END
```

My question is how to use above code  for each different values.
Job run:   select count(*) from jobrun= 3905877

```
accountid           Interfaceid                started  
13                    2                        2017-01-21 08:30:04:500

13                    2                        2017-01-21 08:34:50:250 

13                    2                        2016-12-29 08:30:04:500

13                    4                        2016-05-02 11:43:07:317

AccountInterface:

AccountID                    Id               Autopronejobdays

13                           1                 30

13                           2                 30

10                           3                  0

13                           4                 23 

92                           5                  7
```

Autointerface table has accounted with different ID, data should delete accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

So, the fundamental issue with your first stored procedure is that it's not dealing with a limited set of accounts or interfaces, but with the entire table. This statement:

```
     SELECT MAX(AutoPruneJobDays) AS [AutoPruneJobDays] 
       FROM [dbo].[JobRun] AS JR 
 INNER JOIN [dbo].[AccountInterface] AS AI
         ON JR.[AccountID]=AI.[AccountID]
             AND JR.[InterfaceID]=AI.[ID]
```

will give you back the maximum `AutoPruneJobDays` from all `AccountInterface` rows where the `AccountID` and `InterfaceID` exist in any `JobRun` row. You may have realized this, but I couldn't tell for certain from the question.

Your second stored procedure looks like it will *almost* give you the results you're looking for. There are two possible problems.

First, assuming the logic from the first procedure regarding what to do if there `AutoPruneJobDays` was left NULL or set to 0 holds, you'd want to bring in the CASE statement you had there and use it instead of `@PruneDate` in the second stored procedure:

```
WHERE
       jr.Started < CASE WHEN ai.AutoPruneJobDays IS NULL OR ai.AutoPruneJobDays=0
                         THEN GETUTCDATE()-1
                         ELSE DATEADD(dd,(-1 * ai.AutoPruneJobDays),GETUTCDATE())
                    END
```

Second, if it's possible for a `JobRun` row not to have a matching AccountInterface record, then (as written) the final stored procedure would ignore those `JobRun` rows. My guess is that you'd want those rows to be handled as if they had a NULL `AutoPruneJobDays`. If so, change the `INNER JOIN` in the final procedure to a `LEFT JOIN`.

Putting it all together, you get this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AutoPruneJobRun] 
AS
BEGIN

DELETE jr
FROM [dbo].[JobRun] jr
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AccountInterface] ai ON     ai.AccountID = jr.AccountID
                                                AND ai.ID = jr.InterfaceID
WHERE
       jr.Started < CASE WHEN ai.AutoPruneJobDays IS NULL OR ai.AutoPruneJobDays = 0
                         THEN GETUTCDATE()-1
                         ELSE DATEADD(dd,(-1 * ai.AutoPruneJobDays),GETUTCDATE())
                    END
END
```

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:  OP claims that the above procedure does not correctly use the appropriate `AutoPruneJobDays`, based on the `JobRun` row's `AccountId` and 'InterfaceId`. I thought I'd post additional code, to show that it does.

Here's the code I put together to test this:

```
CREATE TABLE JobRun (accountId int, InterfaceId int, started datetime);
INSERT INTO JobRun
VALUES (13, 2, '2017-01-21 08:30:04:500')
      ,(13, 2, '2017-01-21 08:34:50:250')
      ,(13, 2, '2016-12-29 08:30:04:500')
      ,(13, 4, '2016-05-02 11:43:07:317')
      ,(13, 2, '2017-01-30 11:43:40')
      ,(13, 4, '2017-01-30 11:43:40')
;

CREATE TABLE AccountInterface (Id int, accountId int, AutoPruneJobDays int);
INSERT INTO AccountInterface
VALUES (1, 13, 30)
      ,(2, 13, 30)
      ,(3, 10, 0)
      ,(4, 13, 23)
      ,(5, 92, 7)
;
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SELECT_AutoPrune_ToDelete] 
AS
BEGIN

SELECT jr.accountId, jr.InterfaceId, ai.AutoPruneJobDays, jr.started,
       CASE WHEN ai.AutoPruneJobDays IS NULL OR ai.AutoPruneJobDays = 0
            THEN GETUTCDATE()-1
            ELSE DATEADD(dd,(-1 * ai.AutoPruneJobDays),GETUTCDATE())
       END
       as CutOffDate
FROM [dbo].[JobRun] jr
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AccountInterface] ai ON     ai.AccountID = jr.AccountID
                                                AND ai.ID = jr.InterfaceID
WHERE
       jr.Started < CASE WHEN ai.AutoPruneJobDays IS NULL OR ai.AutoPruneJobDays = 0
                         THEN GETUTCDATE()-1
                         ELSE DATEADD(dd,(-1 * ai.AutoPruneJobDays),GETUTCDATE())
                    END
END;
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AutoPruneJobRun] 
AS
BEGIN

DELETE jr
FROM [dbo].[JobRun] jr
       LEFT JOIN [dbo].[AccountInterface] ai ON     ai.AccountID = jr.AccountID
                                                AND ai.ID = jr.InterfaceID
WHERE
       jr.Started < CASE WHEN ai.AutoPruneJobDays IS NULL OR ai.AutoPruneJobDays = 0
                         THEN GETUTCDATE()-1
                         ELSE DATEADD(dd,(-1 * ai.AutoPruneJobDays),GETUTCDATE())
                    END
END;
GO
```

I'm using the sample data provided; however, I've added two records. Both are for account ID 13, both have a started date of Jan 30, 2017; one is `InterfaceId` 2 (with auto prune days = 30), the other `InterfaceId` 4 (with auto prune days = 23).

In addition, just to show which records will be deleted, I created a copy of the requested stored procedure, that `SELECT` the data that would be deleted, showing the `JobRun` data plus the `AutoPruneJobDays` to be applied, as well as the "cut off date" for that AutoPruneJobDays value - the date before which `JobRun` records will be deleted.

When I run the `SELECT` procedure:

```
EXECUTE SELECT_AutoPrune_ToDelete;
```

I get the following results:

```
accountId   InterfaceId AutoPruneJobDays started                   CutOffDate
----------- ----------- ---------------- -----------------------   -----------------------
13          2           30               2017-01-21 08:30:04.500   2017-01-25 19:26:57.100
13          2           30               2017-01-21 08:34:50.250   2017-01-25 19:26:57.100
13          2           30               2016-12-29 08:30:04.500   2017-01-25 19:26:57.100
13          4           23               2016-05-02 11:43:07.317   2017-02-01 19:26:57.100
13          4           23               2017-01-30 11:43:40.000   2017-02-01 19:26:57.100
```

Note that the `JobRun` record with a `started` date of Jan 30, 2017, and an InterfaceId` of 2 does not appear, since it's not 30 days old yet.

And, when I run the `DELETE` procedure:

```
EXECUTE AutoPruneJobRun;
```

I can see that 5 records are deleted, as expected.